# How do I word-wrap links in a table cell so that it doesn't break the flow of the table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and PHP:

```
        <?php
            if ($_POST["submit"] == "Get Articles") {
                $api_url = "https://DonutJuice:so%20many%20people%20in%20my%20bed@api.pinboard.in/v1/posts/all?format=json";

                $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                $json = curl_exec($ch);

                curl_close($ch);

                $values = json_decode($json, true);

                echo "<div class='article-output'>";
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr><th>URL</th> <th>Title</th></tr>";

                foreach ($values as $bookmark) {
                    $bookmark_url = $bookmark["href"];
                    $bookmark_title = $bookmark["description"];
                    echo "<tr><td><a href='" . $bookmark_url . "'>" . $bookmark_url . "</a></td> <td>" . $bookmark_title . "</td></tr>";
                }

                echo "</table>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
```

With this CSS:

```
table {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 5px 20px;

    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #a9a8a7;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

tr {
    height: 50px;
}

th {
    color: #173769;
}

td {
    width: 60px;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    color: #444;
}

    td:first-child {
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
```

But whenever I press the button that processes that PHP, I get things like this:

[image]

Where they're still breaking the page layout ruthlessly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: CSS questions require generated HTML

Comment: It's rather obvious what it will be.

Comment: Yes, its obvious that it will be a table with text in it.  Except you're forcing the people who are interested in helping you to write out the code by hand instead of taking the time to provide code they can quickly copy/paste into their demoing tool of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `word-break` property can force wrapping to occur when the lines are too long

http://tinker.io/ca0ae

```
td {
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Given link ist dead: `Cannot GET /ca0ae`

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it on the [PHP side](https://www.php.net/wordwrap):

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='" . $bookmark_url . "'>" . wordwrap($bookmark_url, 40, "\n") . "</a></td> <td>" . $bookmark_title . "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `td` in CSS:

```
td {
    width: 60px;
    color: #444;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```